# NSFetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles property

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've implemented an `NSFetchedResultsController` correctly so that it splits up my fetched data by sections. When I try print out its property `sectionIndexTitles` I just get `"0"`, but if I iterate over its sections and print out the section names it prints out each section's name:

```
dump(fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles)
    // prints out "0"
var names = [String]()
for val in (fetchedResultsController.sections)! {
    names.append(val.name)
}
dump(names)
    // prints out:  - "03/31/2017"
                    - "04/01/2017"
                    - "04/02/2017"
```

I thought the `sectionIndexTitles` returns an array of all the sections' names, is that incorrect?

Comment: The `sectionIndexTitles` relate to the index that can be used in table views - see the Contacts app for example - showing (normally) the initial letters of the names of each section.  Because your section names all begin with "0", that is the only index title that is required.

Comment: Ok, So I guess to make an array of the actual section names I need to loop over my sections like I'm doing in my code above.

Comment: Do you need a separate array?  Why not just use the frc.sections array and access the name property when necessary?

Comment: I do need an array, I'm using the iOS charts library that needs an array for a certain function.

Comment: Ah.  You could use .map to avoid looping: `let sectionNames = fetchedResultsController.sections!.map { $0.name }`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.map` loops anyways, how else would it iterate over every value?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Just slightly neater to code/read?  Up to you.